# "Assertion 'iFuncWrapper' failed" when using valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have the following C program test.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"

int convertVideo(const char *in_filename, const char *out_filename)
{
  AVFormatContext *input_format_context = avformat_alloc_context();
  AVPacket pkt;

  int ret, i;
  int frame_index = 0;
  av_register_all();
  // Input
  if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&input_format_context, in_filename, NULL,
                                 NULL)) < 0)
  {
    printf("Could not open input file.");
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Format %s, duration %lld us\n",
           input_format_context->iformat->long_name,
           input_format_context->duration);
  }
  if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(input_format_context, 0)) < 0)
  {
    printf("Failed to retrieve input stream information");
    return 1;
  }
  AVFormatContext *output_format_context = avformat_alloc_context();
  AVPacket packet;
  int stream_index = 0;
  int *streams_list = NULL;
  int number_of_streams = 0;
  int fragmented_mp4_options = 0;
  avformat_alloc_output_context2(&output_format_context, NULL, NULL,
                                 out_filename);
  if (!output_format_context)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create output context\n");
    ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    return 1;
  }
  AVOutputFormat *fmt = av_guess_format(0, out_filename, 0);
  output_format_context->oformat = fmt;

  number_of_streams = input_format_context->nb_streams;
  streams_list =
      (int *)av_mallocz_array(number_of_streams, sizeof(*streams_list));

  if (!streams_list)
  {
    ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    return 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < input_format_context->nb_streams; i++)
  {
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream = input_format_context->streams[i];
    AVCodecParameters *in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
    if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
        in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO &&
        in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE)
    {
      streams_list[i] = -1;
      continue;
    }
    streams_list[i] = stream_index++;

    out_stream = avformat_new_stream(output_format_context, NULL);
    if (!out_stream)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
      ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
      return 1;
    }
    ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  av_dump_format(output_format_context, 0, out_filename, 1);
  // unless it's a no file (we'll talk later about that) write to the disk
  // (FLAG_WRITE) but basically it's a way to save the file to a buffer so you
  // can store it wherever you want.
  if (!(output_format_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
  {
    ret = avio_open(&output_format_context->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
      return 1;
    }
  }
  AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
  ret = avformat_write_header(output_format_context, &opts);
  if (ret < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int n = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
    ret = av_read_frame(input_format_context, &packet);
    if (ret < 0)
      break;
    in_stream = input_format_context->streams[packet.stream_index];
    if (packet.stream_index >= number_of_streams ||
        streams_list[packet.stream_index] < 0)
    {
      av_packet_unref(&packet);
      continue;
    }
    packet.stream_index = streams_list[packet.stream_index];

    out_stream = output_format_context->streams[packet.stream_index];
    // out_stream->time_base = {1, 30};
    /* copy packet */

    // AVRational time_base;
    // out_stream->time_base = time_base;
    // out_stream->time_base.den = 34;
    // out_stream->time_base.num = 1;

    out_stream->codec->time_base.num = 1;
    out_stream->codec->time_base.den = 30;

    // packet.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(
    //     packet.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base,
    //     static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    // packet.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(
    //     packet.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base,
    //     static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    // packet.duration = av_rescale_q(packet.duration, in_stream->time_base,
    //                                out_stream->time_base);

    packet.pts = n * 3000;
    packet.dts = n * 3000;
    packet.duration = 3000;

    packet.pos = -1;

    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(output_format_context, &packet);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
      break;
    }
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    n++;
  }
  // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga7f14007e7dc8f481f054b21614dfec13
  av_write_trailer(output_format_context);
  avformat_close_input(&input_format_context);
  /* close output */
  if (output_format_context &&
      !(output_format_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    avio_closep(&output_format_context->pb);
  avformat_free_context(output_format_context);
  av_freep(&streams_list);
  if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred\n");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int result = convertVideo("/home/admin/video.dump", "/home/admin/video.mp4");
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with

```
gcc -g test.c -o test -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale
```

which doesn't return any errors when compiling or linking and also works when executing it.  I now want to check for memory leaks with

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose ./test
```

But this gives me the output

```
verbose ./test
==15196== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15196== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15196== Using Valgrind-3.17.0-07f0cdcbb4-20210319X and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15196== Command: ./test
==15196==
--15196-- Valgrind options:
--15196--    --leak-check=full
--15196--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--15196--    --track-origins=yes
--15196--    --verbose
--15196-- Contents of /proc/version:
--15196--   Linux version 5.4.3-23.cm1 (root@mariner) (gcc version 9.1.0 (GCC)) #1-mariner SMP PREEMPT Tue May 11 22:19:15 UTC 2021
--15196--
--15196-- Arch and hwcaps: ARM64, LittleEndian, v8
--15196-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 65536
--15196-- Valgrind library directory: /home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck
--15196-- Reading syms from /var/custom-configs/home/admin/test
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so
--15196-- Reading syms from /var/custom-configs/home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/memcheck-arm64-linux
--15196--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--15196-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--15196-- Reading suppressions file: /home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/default.supp
==15196== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-15196-by-root-on-???
==15196== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-15196-by-root-on-???
==15196== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-15196-by-root-on-???
==15196==
==15196== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==15196== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==15196== or are doing some strange experiment):
==15196==   /home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/../../bin/vgdb --pid=15196 ...command...
==15196==
==15196== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==15196==   /path/to/gdb ./test
==15196== and then give GDB the following command
==15196==   target remote | /home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/../../bin/vgdb --pid=15196
==15196== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==15196==
--15196-- REDIR: 0x4017340 (ld-linux-aarch64.so.1:strlen) redirected to 0x580c8798 (vgPlain_arm64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--15196-- REDIR: 0x40170c0 (ld-linux-aarch64.so.1:strcmp) redirected to 0x580c87ec (vgPlain_arm64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strcmp)
--15196-- REDIR: 0x4016fd0 (ld-linux-aarch64.so.1:index) redirected to 0x580c87c0 (vgPlain_arm64_linux_REDIR_FOR_index)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/vgpreload_core-arm64-linux.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
--15196-- Reading syms from /var/custom-configs/home/admin/valgrind-3.17.0/memcheck/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libavformat.so.57
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libavcodec.so.57
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libavutil.so.55
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libswscale.so.4
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libc-2.28.so
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libm-2.28.so
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libpthread-2.28.so
--15196-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libswresample.so.2

valgrind: m_redir.c:1195 (vgPlain_redir_do_lookup): Assertion 'iFuncWrapper' failed.

host stacktrace:
==15196==    at 0x58046584: show_sched_status_wrk (m_libcassert.c:406)
==15196==    by 0x580466C3: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:477)
==15196==    by 0x58046823: vgPlain_assert_fail (m_libcassert.c:543)
==15196==    by 0x580C60F7: vgPlain_redir_do_lookup (m_redir.c:1195)
==15196==    by 0x58060E0F: vgPlain_translate (m_translate.c:1529)
==15196==    by 0x580A6867: handle_tt_miss (scheduler.c:1138)
==15196==    by 0x580A6867: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1500)
==15196==    by 0x580F2EAB: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:101)
==15196==    by 0x580F2EAB: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:154)
==15196==    by 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 15196)
==15196==    at 0x5DD1778: memcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x400B2D7: _dl_relocate_object (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x4003BEF: dl_main (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x4014C57: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x40018CB: _dl_start_final (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x4001B57: _dl_start (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==15196==    by 0x4001047: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFE000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFFCB0
valgrind stack range: [0x1008EB8000 0x1008FB7FFF] top usage: 14912 of 1048576


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

From other tests I expected to get a summary like this

```
==15415== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15415==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15415==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 5 bytes allocated
==15415==
==15415== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15415==
==15415== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What's the reason why valgrind doesn't work on test.c and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions it gave? "*Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution....If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org*". That is, either FAQ might help or could be a valgrind bug that can be reported.

Comment: @kaylum fair point, I didn't. But I did now and it wasn't helpful. What's a bit unclear for me regarding thd output: Do I interpret this correctly that the problems appears right after valgrind tries to read symbols from /usr/lib/libswresample.so.2?

Comment: No you can't jump to that conclusion. That's the last thing that was printed but it doesn't mean that's the last thing that ran. The stack trace is what gives you the precise location of the crash. If the FAQ didn't help then you may want to search the valgrind bug list and/or log a bug as instructed.

Comment: As a side note, I was just running the exact same program on a different PC with valgrind installed and it works there, I get an ERROR SUMMARY. Notably there are much more "Reading syms from [...]" lines appearing in valgrind